# Unable to send json using ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to send json using ajax but with no success

```
   var json_data = JSON.stringify({"email": "em@il"});

    request = $.ajax({
        url: '/update',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        mimeType: 'application/json',
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: json_data,
    });
```

in inspector I see that request body is empty

```
POST /update HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5005
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Origin: http://localhost:5005
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://localhost:5005/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: jenkins-timestamper-offset=-7200000
```

I dont know what is wrong please help

Comment: don't use `JSON.stringify` and send json data directly in the post call, it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do console.log(json_data );
and check if is a valid json here :
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

try with this script

```
 $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
      },
      url:"/update",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: json_data,
      success: function(resp) {
      
        console.log('Response success : ' ,resp);
    
      }
    });
```